# What does "Seventy-two only" mean in this line from Dracula?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In chapter 25 of *Dracula* by Bram Stoker, Van Helsing says to Mina Harker,

> ”Good, good! Oh, you so clever lady!" said Van Helsing, enthusiastically, as he stooped and kissed her hand. A moment later he said to me, as calmly as though we had been having a sick room consultation, "Seventy-two only, and in all this excitement. I have hope."

What does "Seventy-two only" mean here?

Comment: Has he discreetly taken her pulse during the hand-kissing?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about interpreting the plot narrative; it is better asked on Literature.SE. Answers depend on knowing the plot, and may still be speculative. No fixed expression is involved.

Comment: A normal resting heart rate range is between 60 and 100 bpm.  Usually a healthy smaller person will have a faster heart rate than a healthy larger person. If he took the pulse of a smaller woman for example, 72 bpm would be quite normal and even an indicator of being relaxed.

Comment: Posting on https://literature.stackexchange.com might generate helpful responses.

Answer (score 2):

”Good, good! Oh, you so clever lady!" said Van Helsing, enthusiastically, as he stooped and kissed her hand. A moment later he said to me, as calmly as though we had been having a sick room consultation, "**Seventy-two only**, and in all this excitement. I have hope."

From *The New Annotated Dracula*  [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=h1VhXIak7J8C&lpg=PA458&dq=%22Seventy-two%20only%22%20dracula&pg=PA458#v=onepage&q=%22Seventy-two%20only%22%20&f=false)

> 40 This is a truly amazing talent, to take Mina's pulse in a few
>   seconds while kissing her hand! In short, it's another display of Van
>   Hesling's medical quackery.

My sense: her pulse was normal despite the excitement. Not being a Dracula fan, I leave it to others to comment why Mina should have had an abnormal pulse.

Comment: Your link doesn't lead to that quote, so I can't tell if *or hand* is a typo in the original or not. (It should be *her hand*.)

Comment: @tmgr noted and corrected. tkx